# Extract from array values having keys as values of another array

Tags: php, arrays

Better show than tell.

```
$first = array(
    3=>"Banana", 
    4=>"Apple", 
    6=>"Lemon",
    7=>"Pineapple",
    8=>"Peach"
);

$second = array(4,7,8);
```

(Please note: the first one is associative array, it can have holes)
The result should be

```
$result = array(
    "Apple", 
    "Pineapple",
    "Peach"
);
```

Any smart idea? 
Thank you

Comment: The smartest idea is to read the documentation of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) then use a plain `foreach` to do the job. And, of course, all this takes less time than posting such a question on [so] and waiting for others to solve your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we are using [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php), [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). This single liner will be enough.

> **1.** `array_values` will return values of an array.
>
> **2.** `array_flip` will flip array over `keys` and `values`.
>
> **3.** `array_intersect_key` will return array on the basis of two input array's over intersecting keys.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/866673)

```
print_r(
     array_values(
         array_intersect_key(
                  $first, array_flip($second))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple foreach loop will do it. And isset() checks that the index exists in the first array before trying to read it:

```
$first = array(
    3=>"Banana", 
    4=>"Apple", 
    6=>"Lemon",
    7=>"Pineapple",
    8=>"Peach"
);
$second = array(4,7,8);
$result = array();

foreach($second as $i)
{
    if (isset($first[$i])) $result[] = $first[$i];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$first = array(

    3 => "Banana",
    4 => "Apple",
    6 => "Lemon",
    7 => "Pineapple",
    8 => "Peach"
);

$second = array(4, 7, 8);

foreach ($first as $key => $val) {
    if (array_search($key, $second) === false) {
        unset($first[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($first);
exit;
```